# Trying to assing datepicker value to a variable and getting undefined as assigned

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am trying to select date time from the DatePicker and trying to assign it to a variable to pass as a parameter to ajax post call, but getting **undefined** as result

I want to select date and time in **yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss** format to make a ajax call

```
var sd = $('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
    language: 'eng'
}).val();
console.log(sd);
```

Comment: refer this var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" ); [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain which plugin you are using but I would strongly recommend [bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker) as it is actively maintained.

It sounds as though you are wanting to capture the `hide` event of the `datetimepicker` to run your ajax call. The event for this is `dp.hide`.

So having set up your `datetimepicker`:

```
$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker();
```

Listen for the event:

```
$('#datetimepickerStart').on('dp.hide', function (e) {
    console.log(e);
    console.log(e.date._d);
});
```

Note that you also need the [moment.js](http://momentjs.com) library.

See it working **[in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vzgsv398/)**

Comment: If I will be able to select the date and time from the datetimepicker and assing it to some variable I can take care of Ajax :(

Comment: No it is not working... i want both date and time so am using datetimepicker

Comment: actually you are right, i have wrongly tagged .. iam using bootstrap
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
    </script>

Comment: @AndersLindén you're right, I changed it in an earlier revision and forgot when I updated the umpteenth time figuring out which plugin suma is using.

Comment: @sumashetty if language is no problem, then leave it out of the question.

Comment: <div id="datetimepickerStart" class="input-append date">
  <input type="text" value="Start Date"></input> <span class="add-on">
   <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
 </div>

Comment: @jcuenod nope, date and time is not getting selected at all, I dont know where am going wrong

Comment: though it is working for me this was not what i was looking for :( for every click it is updating date

Comment: As soon as u click on some date it thorws date with some default date, it wont even let u select the time toy want